# Why is my state from useState overwritten?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a form with some complex validation. I would like to not display any errors before one of the two:

1. User have written something wrong
2. The user clicks the Next-button in the form and the values is not valid

So I would like to hold the state of the errors, but I can not see why my errors are not appearing as expected. So I wonder why the error of the first input is overwritten by the one field that is placed last in the file? It only shows the last error.

I could have all the validation on the top-level, but I would rather have the input specific validation on the input level. Such that if others want to use the component, the validation is already in the input component.

Code example below:

```
// Main file
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
const [values, setValues] = useState({
  myFieldNameNo1: null,
  myFieldNameNo2: null,
});

<div>
  <FormContainer errors={errors} setErrors={setErrors} />
  ...
</div>


// FormContainer.jsx

<div>
    <CustomInputNo1 value={values.myFieldNameNo1} setError={error => props.setErrors({ ...props.errors, fieldNameNo1: error }) />
    <CustomInputNo2 value={values.myFieldNameNo2} setError={error => props.setErrors({ ...props.errors, fieldNameNo2: error }) />
</div>

// Inside each of the CustomInputs

useEffect(() => {
  if (someErrorValidationReturnsTrue) {
    props.setError("My error message");
  }
}, [props.value]);
```

Comment: If the `setError` callback is being called in the same tick, the `errors` prop will be the same. This will result in all previous calls being overridden by the last call. You could try passing a callback to the `setError` callback. This will receive the last state as argument: `setError={error => props.setErrors(errors => ({ ...errors, fieldNameNo1: error }))}`

Comment: Thank you very much, both for the explanation and the suggestion, @Christiaan ! It worked to pass a callback to the setError callback.